# GNU make not recognizing %

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to make a makefile for compiling various examples that are within a subfolder. The makefile consisting of just:

```
S_1_2.exe : Twister.cpp Parsing.cpp ./Surfaces/S_1_2.cpp
    g++ -o $@.exe $^ -I . -W -Wall
```

Works fine when run with the command "make S_1_2.exe". However:

```
%S_1_2.exe : Twister.cpp Parsing.cpp ./Surfaces/S_1_2.cpp
    g++ -o $@.exe $^ -I . -W -Wall
```

fails, even when run with the command make S_1_2.exe, with the error "make: *** No rule to make target 'S_1_2.exe'. Stop."

Shouldn't %S_1_2.exe do pattern matching and so match S_1_2.exe? In which case why is it not matching this rule?

I am using GNU Make 3.81

Comment: Are you sure that those three source files exist?

Comment: Yes, they all exist. Like I said the first command runs fine and that has the exact same dependencies.

Comment: I'm running GNUMake 3.81, and I get the same error with `%S_1_2.exe`, but with `%_1_2.exe` I get the error only when one of the sources is missing.

Answer (score 1):

The percentage symbol matches a non-empty string. So you should use `%_1_2.exe` or better yet - `%.exe`. I don't know if there is any other symbol that matches empty strings too.

Comment: Even with %_1_2.exe or %.exe I still get the same problem

Answer (score 1):

The `%` is for matching a part of the target against the same part in one or more dependencies.
You can't omit it from all dependencies.